# How can I detect if a device has a touch screen in Titanium?

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I'm targeting Android with Titanium. How can I tell if a device has a touch screen or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with. It's really stupid, but it works. Wherever you create your application window, add this code:

```
function touchStart(){
    Titanium.App.Properties.setBool("touch", true);

    self.removeEventListener("touchstart", touchStart);
}

self.addEventListener("touchstart", touchStart);
```

Replace `self` with the name of your window. Now, the first time a touch event is detected, an application property will be set.

Later on, check that touch is present with this:

```
var touchSupported = Titanium.App.Properties.getBool("touch", false);
```

If you are testing this on an emulator, the property might persist even when you change "devices". So add this line before anything else:

```
Titanium.App.Properties.setBool("touch", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to test for touch event support. If they are supported, likely the device has a touch screen. If not, it probably doesn't or you can't use them anyway. One solution is:

```
var touchSupported = ('ontouchstart' in window);
```

But be careful as the browser may support touch events but the device might not (e.g. Chrome 20 supports lots of touch events in devices that don't have touch).

You may be able to get users to click a button and see if a touch event is dispatched or just a click.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. I should mention that Titanium doesn't use "standard" event names. Thank you anyway, though.

Comment: How about the "get the user to click a button" idea?

Comment: I did think about that, but I found a way to do it transparently (my answer).

Comment: That's great! Probably should test for touch event support before attaching the listener though.

Comment: I found that the listener always exists (it hasn't thrown an exception yet on a non-touch device). It just doesn't fire if touch support isn't there. Yeah, I know: Titanium has a wonky API